# Font with transparent holes-fill in and outline in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I'm using a font called Nashville. I want to outline only the most outside of the paths. If I try to use the outline tool, it outlines all of the small holes in the font, too. I want to fill in the holes in the font and then outline the most outside paths.

Somehow I got this to work on on block of text, but can't remember how I did it. I used some combination of Outlines, Expand, and Flatten Transparencies.

Font-no outlines

[image: have]

Font-how I want it to look

[image: desired]

Also, is there a way to round the edges of the outline so it's not so spikey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a stroke to the text, then expand and unite via Pathfinder.

Or you could simply switch to Outline Mode (View > Outline) and use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) to select and delate the areas you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your letter art (`Object > Expand...`), degroup, offset the path (`Object > Path > Offset path...`) and if that's not to your liking, try and simpify it (`Object > Path > Simplify...`). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the "spikey" outline, just selected the rounded option for corners in the stroke panel.